# How do I make my contact page working in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple contact page, but everytime I try to send a message, I get an error.

Here is the PHP code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "mailto:benten@benniestudios.eu";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $email, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
echo '<a href="http://www.benniestudios.eu">Return Home</a>';
?>
```

What did I do wrong? If you need more info, please tell me.

Comment: It would be informative if you mentioned what exact error you get.

Comment: The `mailto:` in the `$recipient` is normally used in a HTML link, but probably shouldn't be used here in PHP.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. I get 'Error!', because of this piece of code: `or die("Error!")`. It doesn't give me any other kind of error, but I don't recieve any message. Also, I've tried it without `mailto:` and that won't work either.

Comment: This is the link to the contact form, if it helps: [benniestudios.eu/contact](https://benniestudios.eu/contact/)

Comment: For real error reporting see: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1).

Comment: I found the problem. I removed $subject from the `mail()` function and now it works. Is there a way so I can keep subject?

Comment: Why not read the manual: [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)